# Combine results of grouped-by columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, union

```
Consider table A:

Status                Person
------                ------
Married               Andy
Married               Bob
Married               Carol
Has Kids              Bob
Has Kids              Carol

Consider table B:

Married & Has Kids    Bob
Married & Has Kids    Carol
```

I can get table A and I can get table B, but how do I show A and B together? I'm new to SQL, so I have a vague idea of UNIONs, would that be the best way?

EDIT:

So, I kind of lied. I can't get exactly table B, but similar:

```
Married               Bob
Has Kids              Bob
Married               Carol
Has Kids              Carol
```

I am using SQL Server 2012. Here's my query for table A:

```
SELECT Status,Person
FROM Records
WHERE Status IN ('Married', 'Has Kids')
GROUP BY Status,Person
ORDER BY Status,Person
```

Query for table B-ish:

```
SELECT Status,Person
FROM Records
WHERE Status='Married' AND Status='Has Kids'
GROUP BY Status,Person
ORDER BY Status,Person
```

I **want** a table like this:

```
Status                Person
------                ------
Married               Andy
Married               Bob
Married               Carol
Has Kids              Bob
Has Kids              Carol
Married & Has Kids    Bob
Married & Has Kids    Carol
```

Comment: YES, That would be good.

Comment: `UNION` will remove duplicates if they exist.  `UNION ALL` will keep duplicates if they exist  UNION ALL doesn't have to check for duplicates and thus doesn't have as big of a performance hit as UNION does.  `SELECT Status, person from tableA UNION ALL Select Status, Person from TableB`

Comment: What SQL *Flavor* do you use?  You will need something like `GROUP_CONCAT` for `MySQL` or `LISTAGG` in `Oracle`.

Comment: I think there's some confusion.  If you can generate both of the above results and you want to COMBINE them into one query, then `UNION` seems to make sense.  If you want to generate table B from table A, then some string aggregation using `forXML Path` in SQL server will be needed.  What is it that you have, and what is it that you expect to achieve?

Comment: I think you're correct xQbert, my first problem is combining the statuses into a single field, which the syntax "FOR XML PATH" seems to be the way. My second problem is simple UNION to join the two tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is to use a self join and concatenate the statuses together:

```
select status, person from a
union all
select concat(married.status, ' & ', kids.status) status, kids.person
from a kids 
join a married on kids.Person = married.Person
where kids.Status = 'Has Kids' and married.Status = 'Married'
```

This will give you the exact output in your example.

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/40c37/2)

Or you could use a correlated subquery with `for xml path` as suggested:

```
SELECT Status, Person FROM A 
UNION ALL
SELECT Status = LTRIM(STUFF((
          SELECT '& ' + a.Status
          FROM a 
          WHERE a.Person = a1.Person
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, ''))
        , person 
FROM A A1 GROUP BY Person HAVING COUNT(Status) = 2
```

Comment: WOAH, amazing. Perfect answer and I should have known there was a SQL fiddle. Thank you sir!

Comment: I'm really close, but I keep getting an error: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/63f26/5

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you mean by "together".

If you want the query to return 7 rows, ie. the 5 rows from table A "concatenated" with the 2 rows from table B, then a `UNION` is exactly what you need.

Alternatively, if you want the query to return 5 rows with 3 columns, e.g. Person, Status from A, and Status from B, then a `JOIN` is what you need.

First, the UNION. By default, `UNION` will eliminate duplicate records. If you want duplicate records returned, or if you know that there can be no duplicate records, then you should use `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT Status, Person FROM A
UNION ALL
SELECT Status, Person FROM B

Status                Person
------                ------
Married               Andy
Married               Bob
Married               Carol
Has Kids              Bob
Has Kids              Carol
Married & Has Kids    Bob
Married & Has Kids    Carol
```

For JOIN you have the choice of `JOIN`, `LEFT JOIN`, `RIGHT JOIN` or `FULL JOIN`. The first is also called an `INNER JOIN` and the other 3 are called outer joins, e.g. `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. Personally, I never use the superfluous INNER/OUTER keyword.

Joins have a join criteria, which in your case would be to join table A and B by Person. An inner join will only return records where the Person exists in both A and B, while an outer join will return all records from either table (LEFT/RIGHT) or both tables (FULL). All possible combinations will be returned, e.g. if both table A and table B had 3 records for Person X, then 9 rows would be returned by the query.

For the examples below, I will assume that table B also have a record for `Dan`, in order to illustrate the differences.

Inner Join:

```
SELECT A.Person, A.Status AS StatusA, B.Status AS StatusB
  FROM A
  JOIN B ON B.Person = A.Person

Person    StatusA     StatusB
------    -------     -------
Bob       Married     Married & Has Kids
Carol     Married     Married & Has Kids
Bob       Has Kids    Married & Has Kids
Carol     Has Kids    Married & Has Kids
```

Left Outer Join:

```
SELECT A.Person, A.Status AS StatusA, B.Status AS StatusB
  FROM A
  LEFT JOIN B ON B.Person = A.Person

Person    StatusA     StatusB
------    -------     -------
Andy      Married
Bob       Married     Married & Has Kids
Carol     Married     Married & Has Kids
Bob       Has Kids    Married & Has Kids
Carol     Has Kids    Married & Has Kids
```

Right Outer Join:

```
SELECT B.Person, A.Status AS StatusA, B.Status AS StatusB
  FROM A
  RIGHT JOIN B ON B.Person = A.Person

Person    StatusA     StatusB
------    -------     -------
Bob       Married     Married & Has Kids
Carol     Married     Married & Has Kids
Bob       Has Kids    Married & Has Kids
Carol     Has Kids    Married & Has Kids
Dan                   Married & Has Kids
```

Full Outer Join:

```
SELECT A.Person AS PersonA, A.Status AS StatusA
     , B.Person AS PersonB, B.Status AS StatusB
  FROM A
  JOIN B ON B.Person = A.Person

PersonA    StatusA     PersonB    StatusB
-------    -------     -------    -------
Andy       Married
Bob        Married     Bob        Married & Has Kids
Carol      Married     Carol      Married & Has Kids
Bob        Has Kids    Bob        Married & Has Kids
Carol      Has Kids    Carol      Married & Has Kids
                       Dan        Married & Has Kids
```

Note: Remember that SQL doesn't guarantee ordering unless explicitly specified with an `ORDER BY` clause, so the rows shown above may be returned in a different order.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, I think xQbert is correct about "FOR XML PATH". I should have been clearer in my question about wanting to concatenate the status into a single field.

Comment: I can't vote yet, but jpw's answer is exactly what you need, according to your updated question.